# Вопрос по typedef шаблонов

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Допустим у меня есть базовый шаблонный класс MatrixBase, в котором реализованы конструкоры, операторы умножения, сложения, доступа к данным, и тп:

```
template< int rows, int columns, typename type >
class MatrixBase  {
    public:
                                            MatrixBase();
                                            MatrixBase( std::initializer_list<type> list );
                                           ~MatrixBase();

        MatrixBase<rows, columns, type>&    operator=( const MatrixBase<rows, columns, type>& other );

        template<int otherColumns>
        MatrixBase<rows, otherColumns, type> operator*( MatrixBase<columns, otherColumns, type>& other );

        type&                               operator()( int row, int column );
};
```

И наследованный шаблонный класс MatrixSquare у которого есть методы свойственные квадратной матрице, такие как определитель, транспонирование, и подобное:

```
template< int dimension, typename type >
class MatrixSquare : public MatrixBase<dimension, dimension, type> {
public:
                                                MatrixSquare();
                                                MatrixSquare( std::initializer_list<type> list ) : MatrixBase<dimension, dimension, type>(list) {};
                                               ~MatrixSquare();

    MatrixSquare<dimension, type>               inverse();
    MatrixSquare<dimension, type>               transponse();
    type&                                       determinant();
```

};

И теперь я хочу определить шаблон, который бы сам определял, какой класс нужно подобрать, в зависимости от значения параметров. Что-то вроде этого:

```
Matrix<3,3,double>    ->     MatrixSquare<3,double>
Matrix<1,4,int>       ->     MatrixBase<1,4,int>
```

Пока я додумался до такого:

```
template <int rows, int columns, typename type>
using Matrix = MatrixBase<rows, columns, type>;

template <int rows, typename type>
using Matrix = MatrixSquare<rows, type>;
```

А хотелось бы еще такого:

```
template <int rows, int rows, typename type>
using Matrix = MatrixSquare<rows, type>;
```

Можно ли сделать так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да. Такое можно реализовать специализацией шаблонов классов:

```
template< int rows, int columns, typename type >
class Matrix
{
    int matrixType() const {return 0;}
    // общие функции для всех типов матриц
};

template<int size, typename type > // специализация для квадратных матриц 
class Matrix<size, size, type>   
{
    int matrixType() const {return 1;}
    // частные реализации общих функции + частные функции
};

// проверяем
auto t1 = Matrix<3,4,int>().matrixType(); // 0  
auto t2 = Matrix<5,5,int>().matrixType(); // 1
```

Однако здесь понадобиться реализовывать общие функций столько раз сколько у нас специализаций, что порождает дублирование кода. Чтобы решить эту проблему, можно попробовать вынести общие реализации в третий класс и отнаследовать от него все специализации:

```
template< int rows, int columns, typename type >
class MatrixBase
{
    // общие функции для всех типов матриц
};

template< int rows, int columns, typename type >
class Matrix : public MatrixBase<rows,columns,type>
{
   int matrixType() const {return 0;}
   // ...
};

template<int size, typename type > // специализация для квадратных матриц 
class Matrix<size, size, type> : public MatrixBase<size, size, type>
{
    int matrixType() const {return 1;}
    // частные функции
};
```

Класс `MatrixSquare` теперь будет просто шаблонным псевдонимом (для Си++11 и старше):

```
template<int dimention, typename type>
using MatrixSquare = Matrix<dimention, diemention, type>;
```