# Вопрос по шаблонам

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Возник небольшой вопрос по шаблонам.

Допустим, я хочу сделать статическую шаблонную библиотеку по работе с матрицами. И тут сразу возникают вопросы.

Есть методы, которые должны работать только с квадратными матрицами, например, обращение и вычисление определителя.
Есть методы, которые должны работать только для определенного размера матрицы: например для матрицы 3х3 хорошо было бы иметь метод получения углов Эйлера и кватерниона.
Для матриц с количеством строк равным единице (по сути векторов) нужно определить скалярное и векторное умножение, и операцию доступа к элементам по одному индексу.
Для матрицы размером 2х1 или двумерного вектора хорошо было бы определить .x(), .y() а для 3х1 методы .x(), .y(), .z().

Можно было бы просто определить все эти методы в базовом классе, но тогда компилятор будет пропускать векторное умножение двух квадратных матриц, и тому подобное. Максимум что можно сделать это проверку корректности во время выполнения программы. Но этот подход меня не устраивает.

Я, вижу два подхода:

1. Сделать базовый шаблонный класс Matrix. А все остальное делать специализаций шаблонов. Но, насколько я понял, в этом случае придется каждый раз переписывать все общие методы. Или же можно при помощи специализации только добавлять к шаблонному классу методы, не переписывая старые?
2. Сделать базовый шаблонный класс MatrixBase и создавать классы потомки базового типа MatrixSquare, MatrixSquare3, Vector, Vector3 и тому подобное.
   Но и тут возникают вопросы. Что возвращать в результате перемножения MatrixSquare<3> на Vector<3>? MatrixBase<3x1> или Vector<3>? Может понадобиться и то и другое. Какие еще подводные камни могут быть при таком подходе?

Comment: "но тогда компилятор будет пропускать векторное умножение двух квадратных матриц, и тому подобное" - не совсем понятно, что Вы тут имели ввиду, можно уточнить?

Comment: Я имел в виду что если для всех видов матриц и векторов оставить единый класс, то тогда все операции, специфичные для некоторых типов матриц (например вычисление определителя, которое определенно только для квадратных матриц), распространяться и на другие типы.  И на этапе компиляции не удастся отловить моменты когда вычисляется определитель от столбца.

Answer (score 1):

Не мешайте в одну кучу модель представления данных и контролы для управления ими. Не надо матрицам уметь с собой делать что-то более сложное, чем доступ на чтение и запись значений.

Пусть у Вас будет иерархия матриц (как угодно, можете через специализации шаблонов, можете через классическое наследование).

Она состоит из:

вектор - и его подтипы вектора длины 2 и 3.

квадратная матрица, и ее подтипы матрицы со стороной 2 и 3.

Все остальные матрицы.

Каждый из типов обладает уникальными функциями. И подтипы наследуют эти функции.

Я бы выделил такую модель данных:

```
template<typename T, int X, int Y>
struct base_matrix
{
   T _data[X*Y];
};
template<typename T, int X> struct matrix_vector : public base_matrix<T, X, 1> {};
template<typename T> struct matrix_2x1 : public matrix_vector<T, 2> {};
template<typename T> struct matrix_3x1 : public matrix_vector<T, 3> {};

template<typename T, int X> struct matrix_quadro : public base_matrix<T, X, X> {};
template<typename T> struct matrix_2x2 : public matrix_quadro<T, 2> {};
template<typename T> struct matrix_3x3 : public matrix_quadro<T, 3> {};

struct matrixControl 
{
   template<typename T, int X> void method_for_quad1(matrix_quadro<T, X>& mq) { /*...*/ }
   template<typename T, int X> void method_for_quad2(matrix_quadro<T, X>& mq) { /*...*/ }
   template<typename T, int X> void method_for_vector1(matrix_vector<T, X>& mq) { /*...*/ }
   template<typename T> void method_for_2x1(matrix_2x1<T>& mq) { /*...*/ }
   template<typename T, X, Y> void method_for_all1(base_matrix<T, X, Y>& mq) { /*...*/ }
};
```

Доступ до размеров внутри шаблонного класса Вы просто имеете по имени шаблонного параметра.

Теперь Вы или можете разнести реализацию указанным выше способом, сортируя "подходящие" матрицы просто по типу, как входной параметр функций.

Кроме того, Вам на помощь придут статические проверки всех мастей и разновидностей, коих в C++ множество.

Если `X!=Y`, например, в функции, которая имеет смысл только для квадратных матриц, на этапе компиляции можно прерваться с выводом ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

1. Решение из моего [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474411/180450) на другой ваш вопрос отвечает положительно на первый пункт.
2. Это же решение отвечает отрицательно на второй пункт. То есть не надо делать классы с отдельными именами под каждый вид матриц. Делайте отдельные специализации под каждый вид. Как выполнять контроль типов? Ведь мы ради этого и продали душу шаблонному дьяволу! Очень просто - не нужно зацикливаться на классах, реализуйте функции для работы с матрицами в отдельных функциях. Например вот заголовок для функции вычисляющей определитель:

```
template<int DIM, typename type>
type determinant(const Matrix<DIM,DIM,type> & matrix)
{
     //...
}
```

Если вы подставите аргументом неквадратную матрицу, код не скомпилируется. Чего и требовалось достичь.

Comment: +1, но если бы вы привели пример кода (например, чтобы в 3-мерном векторе автоматически возникали `.x()`, `.y()` и `.z()`), было бы нагляднее и лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Идея примерно такая: http://ideone.com/GlEnf3

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <unsigned n> class row_base {
    public: int data[n];
};

template <unsigned n, unsigned s> class row_exts : public row_base<s> {
};

template <unsigned s> class row_exts <1,s> : public row_base<s> {
    public: int &x(void) {
        return this->data[0];
    }
};

template <unsigned s> class row_exts <2,s> : public row_exts<1,s> {
    public: int &y(void) {
        return this->data[1];
    }
};

template <unsigned n> class row : public row_base<n> {};
template <> class row<1> : public row_exts<1,1> {};
template <> class row<2> : public row_exts<2,2> {};

int main() {
    row <2> a;

    a.x() = 42;
    a.y() = -1;
    cout << a.x() << ' ' << a.y();

    return 0;
}
```

Или даже так: http://ideone.com/xiPCph

```
template <unsigned n> class row : public row_exts<n,n> {};
```

---

Кажется, я забыл дописать virtual при наследовании. В данном случае это несущественно, т. к. множетственного наследования нет, но вообще, надо сделать.